# Stability of the Solar System

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics

> **Is the Solar System stable?**

You can see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_of_the_Solar_System) Wikipedia page.
In May 2015 I was at the conference of Cedric Villani at Sharif university of technology with this title: "Of planets, stars and eternity (stabilization and long-time behavior in classical celestial mechanics)"
, at the end of this conference one of the students asked him this question and he laughed strangely(!) with no convincing answer!
**Edit**: The purpose of "long-time" is timescale more than [Lyapunov time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_time), hence billions of years.

Comment: Depends on your notion of stable.  I'm basing many of my plans on the assumption that civilization will be around long enough to support my children and their children.  Gerhard "Knows It's A Risky Assumption" Paseman, 2015.07.03

Comment: If you give a somewhat mathematically rigorous definition of the stability, partial (numerical) answers can be found in J. Laskar's papers.

Comment: Although it's been about 10 years since Pluto was demoted from the list of planets, it still looks strange to me to see "8 planets" instead of 9. Perhaps billions of years from now there will be 15 planets after the opposing astronomers make another definition of what a planet is that lets in Pluto and its cousins. A relevant question is whether the definition of a planet will remain stable.

Comment: Not only is the solar system unstable, but try getting a plumber on weekends.

Comment: Wittyness aside, there are some real questions here before one can begin to answer. For example: On what timescale do you want stability? The solar system might be stable for the next million years or so but unstable if you look billions of years into the future. Consider for example that the number of planets has decreased over the last few billion years through collisions. Who is to say that earth won't collide with mars in the future for example?

Comment: It also depends on the notion of "Solar System": if it comprises "parabolic" objects like comets (and I believe it should), then it is not stable at all. From my point of view, "stable" and "periodic" are interchangeable terms. Besides, how can you predict when/why/where a distant iceberg will decide to dive into the sun?

Comment: @G_infinity: Yes,you are in right, but usually we consider the solar system as the sun and 8 planets. If the planets masses (specially Jupiter) was small, then we had stable solar system (sun + 8 planets) by [KAM theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Arnold%E2%80%93Moser_theorem).

Comment: I suspect that the reason Villani laughed is that this is one of those questions that seems well-defined but isn't, and has a long and somewhat controversial history. Saying "the sun and 8 planets" seems to make the question well-defined, but are you assuming classical mechanics? What about general relativity? How long before the sun goes nova? Do you want a theorem or a numerical simulation? How close does a theorem have to be to "reality" before you consider the problem "solved"? It's O.K. to assume away the dwarf planets but not to assume that Jupiter is smaller than it is? Etc.

Comment: When we couldn't solve the 3-body problem even in the special case:"two sun + 1 planet with zero mass" ([this site have a nice simulation for this](http://www.upscale.utoronto.ca/GeneralInterest/Harrison/Flash/Chaos/ThreeBody/ThreeBody.html)) by simple formula of Newton's law of gravity, then we have't any chance to solve this problem with general relativity or solve this for N-bodies. Hence for solve the problem of the stabilization of the solar system, it's better that we go to the numerical simulation and statistical sense.(at least now)

Comment: @2000 : It doesn't follow from the insolubility of the 3-body problem that the (classical) stability of the solar system is also insoluble.  As you yourself mentioned, KAM theory allows us to prove the stability of some solar-system-like arrangements.

Comment: @Timothy Chow: It is clear that every one prefer a theorem in comparison of numerical solution or statistical sense. But for find the theorem for stability of the solar system  KAM theory failed and until now, we couldn't solve the N-body problem for complex cases (even in simple cases that i mentioned) like solar system.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Due to chaotic behaviour of the Solar System, it is not possible to precisely predict the evolution of the Solar System over 5 Gyr and the question of its long-term stability can only be answered in a statistical sense. For example, in
http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v459/n7248/full/nature08096.html (Existence of collisional trajectories of Mercury, Mars and Venus with the Earth, by 
J. Laskar and M. Gastineau) 2501 orbits with different initial conditions all consistent with our present knowledge of the parameters of the Solar System were
traced out in computer simulations up to 5 Gyr. The main finding of the paper is that one percent of the solutions lead to a large enough increase in Mercury's eccentricity to allow its collisions with Venus or the Sun.

Probably the most surprising result of the paper (see also http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.5996) is that in a pure Newtonian world the probability of collisions within 5 Gyr grows to 60 percent and therefore general relativity is crucial for long-term stability of the inner solar system.

Many questions remain, however, about reliability of the present day consensus that the odds for the catastrophic destabilization of the inner planets are in the order of a few percent. I do not know if the effects of galactic tidal perturbations or possible perturbations from passing stars are taken into account. Also different numerical algorithms lead to statistically different results (see, for example, http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.07602).

Some interesting historical background of solar system stability studies can be found in http://arxiv.org/abs/1411.4930 (Michel Henon and the Stability of the Solar System, by Jacques Laskar).

Answer (score 16):

[This paper](http://iopscience.iop.org/0004-637X/683/2/1207/fulltext/) (Batyrin and Laughlin, 2008) seems to indicate that we are doomed.

Comment: "Doomed" in what sense?  Gerhard "Igor's Not From Around Here?" Paseman, 2015.07.03

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Planets leaving, other planets crashing into the Sun. O, the humanity!

Comment: Seems to me (from skimming the paper) that Earth and the gas giants had orbits stable enough to last until the sun burns out.  Of course, if you're planning to move to Mars long term, you might reconsider.  Gerhard "It's Not Like Bradbury Said" Paseman, 2015.07.03

Comment: First, they came for Mars...

Comment: I'm not moving anywhere! It was honour to play with you guys!

Comment: You convinced me against moving to Mars.

Answer (score 6):

in a conference in Paris, Jacques Féjoz said (and i quote from memory) that the big planets seem to be stable, while the small ones chaotic. if i remember well, it was based on numerical evidence, intuition and the known results on the stability of the planar many-body problem...

Answer (score 5):

The work of Wisdom is relevant (for example, see http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/413/1844/109.short) but not conclusive.  Numerical work suggests overall stability over very long time periods.

Comment: Thanks. And i find these PDF files:http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/users/wisdom/chaoticss.pdf and  http://web.mit.edu/wisdom/www/ss-chaos.pdf